# Using ConvertAll to conver to array of objects

Tags: c#

Am I misunderstanding what ConvertAll does or just not understanding something, because I took it to be change the type and not just cast.

So I'm wondering how a StringBuilder (or any class) can be converted to another base class (or in this case object) and still keep its data and type.

```
StringBuilder[] y = new StringBuilder[] { new StringBuilder("a"), new StringBuilder("b"), new StringBuilder("c") };
object[] objectArray1 = Array.ConvertAll<StringBuilder, object>(y, (x2) => (object)x2);
```

In the above, the new array is of objects, but still contains StringBuilder items. I thought the new array would be of the new type, so essentially lose all the original data, e.g. converting from int to string via a conversion would give you a brand new array of strings.

As in,

```
string[] array2 = Array.ConvertAll(array1,
        element => element.ToString());
```

Would give you a new array of strings.

thanks.

Comment: There is no way to change the type of an object.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Fabjan, Maybe I'm not getting something, that's just a cast, I thought ConvertAll actually converted from one type to another, like string to int, etc. so thought convert to an object would lose all data.

Comment: @NeilWalker It looks like you might be confusing a few things here, `object` is just a base type for pretty much everything. There is no way of converting derived type to 'pure object' or something like that. Method `.ToString` basically creates a *new* string from object and that's it

Comment: @fabjan, yes, that's what confused me about how the conversion to object worked, but was explained in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `ConvertAll()` does is change the type of the reference. So you have a StringBuilder reference, and you copy that reference to a variable of type `object`:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.AppendLine("Hello, World!");

object converted = (object)builder;
```

Now `converted` holds an `object` reference, but the actual object it's pointing to still is the `StringBuilder` that you instantiated.

The same is happening in the delegate you create. You can't just cast something to a base class and "cut off" all parts that aren't in the base class.

If you have a scenario where you think you need this, create a custom conversion.

Comment: Ah, so it's the conversion method you pass in that makes it 'convert', so my example simpy casted it as a an object, but 'ToString' changes it to a string?

Comment: Yes, that calls the `ToString()` method on your `StringBuilder` and returns the resulting string.